# Keycloak- passed parameter to meet password policy requirements

Tags: php, symfony, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I have defined get Keycloak method on my Symfony project.

I am getting excepted results in the matter of array where I am extracting the list of password policies. Currently it's set just 'not username' rule:

[image]

I could not find any other endpoint within keycloak in a documentation where I can pass my password string as parameter and see if it's meeting the requirements defined in `password policies`.

I will provide `GET` function which is returning the thing I just described. I think it will do the work if it could be modified to provide password string.

```
public function validateKeycloakPassword()
{
    $options = [
        'headers' => $this->getAuthJsonHeaders()

    ];

    try {
        $endpoint = sprintf('auth/admin/realms/%s/', $this->realm);
        return $this->request('GET', $endpoint, $options);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->exception('Can`t get password policy information on Keycloak. ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

and in my controller, endpoint:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/check", name="check")
 */
public function validatePassword()
{

    $violations = $this->service->validateKeycloakPassword();
    return $violations['passwordPolicy'];
}
```

To summerize:

Is there any endpoint in keycloak where I can pass my password variable and check if it meets requirements defined in `password policies` Probably with `PUT` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** The `/auth` path was removed starting with [Keycloak 17 Quarkus distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71902419/1366871). So you might need to remove the `/auth` from the endpoint calls presented on this answer.

---

As far as I know there is no such endpoint. Nevertheless, there is a workaround that you can do, create a `dummy_user` that will be used to test the passwords. Get the `ID` from that user, which you can get from the Keycloak Admin console or by using the endpoint:

```
curl -X GET  <KEYCLOAK_HOST>/auth/admin/realms/<REALM_NAME>/users/?username=dummy_user
```

From the `JSON` response, extract the user `ID`. Then you call the following endpoint:

```
PUT <KEYCLOAK_HOST>/auth/admin/realms/<REALM_NAME>/users/<USER_ID>/reset-password
```

with the request payload:

```
{"type":"password","value":"<THE_PASSWORD_THAT_YOU_WANT_TO_TEST>","temporary":false}
```

You will get a `400` if the password is not valid, and with the response you can look at the error. An example of such response:

```
error:"invalidPasswordMinLengthMessage"
error_description:"Invalid password minimum length 8"
```

Obviously, this will not work for the `username` policy, but that one can be easily check in your app (*e.g.,* `password != username`)